# Why do we need to change the (weight decay) regularization parameter when changing the number of inputs that neural network is being trained with?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am currently working my way through Michael Nielsen's ebook [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) and I am reading about [overfitting and (L2) regularization](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#regularization). In this subsection, the process of L2 (a.k.a weight decay) regularization is introduced as being the process of adding the term
$$
\frac{\lambda}{2n} \sum w^2
$$
to the cost function so that it becomes
$$
C = C_0 + \frac{\lambda}{2n} \sum w^2
$$
where $C_0$ is the original cost function, $\lambda$ is the regularization parameter, $n$ is the number of items of training data being used, and the sum is over all of the weights in the network.

Later in this chapter, the process of [choosing hyperparameters](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#how_to_choose_a_neural_network's_hyper-parameters) is discussed and the following is said:

> In the above example [when we were using a training set of size 10,000] I left $\lambda$ as $\lambda = 1000.0$, as we used earlier. But since we changed the number of training examples [to 1,000] we should really change $\lambda$ to keep the weight decay the same. That means changing $\lambda$ to $20.0$.

Why would changing the number of training examples mean that we should change the value of the regularization parameter $\lambda$?